# Is there anyway to undo the bitwise or?

Tags: python, boolean, bit-manipulation, logical-operators, logical-or

Say I have `z = x | y` in python. I have z and x, but I don't have y, which is `z = x (bitwise) or y`. `|` is the bitwise operator.

For something more visual:

```
>>> 0b10110101 | 0b10001001 == 0b10111101
True
```

but say I only have this:

```
>>> 0b10110101 | x == 0b10111101
True
```

I want to solve for x. Is there a pythonic solution to my problem?

Comment: Short answer. No. (Not "pythonic" or elsewise either.)

Comment: @PM yes, I read my post and realized I never mentioned it once good spot

Comment: Just look at your example. The least significant bit of 'x' can be either '1' or '0', and the equality can still be satisfied. So there is no solution.

Comment: @John Oh... I wonder where my brain was when I was asking this question... I see what you're saying, in `x | 1 = 1` x can be 0 or 1 making it impossible to solve for it.

Comment: Exactly. For your example there are `2**5 = 32` possible solutions. Now if you were asking about *exclusive* or, `^`, it'd be a different story.

Comment: @PM Well, It could be useful to know how to solve for bitwise xor, could you tell me or direct me to a post where I can find the answer?

Comment: If `a = b ^ c` then `c = a ^ b`. Just take a look at the truth table.

Comment: @PM oh so xor undoes itself? that's great, thanks!

Comment: Yep. That's why it's so handy. Eg, you can use xor to do one-time pad encryption / decryption.